# I'm having trouble getting Derkeethus out of the cave

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I lead Derkeethus to the exit of the cave and then wak out he doesnt come out with me. Is there a different way to get him out? Or am I doing it wrong? (Console)

Answer (score 1):

There is poor routing for followers in that cave. You have to take a few steps at a time, make sure he's following you. Have him very close to you when you finally open the door. He has a really hard time crossing bridges and water. Remember there is the upper and lower exit from that cave, so you can try both.